# Rust Clap Allow value from selected list

Tags: rust, clap

I have a variable

```
     #[clap(
        group = "abc",
        long = "attribute1",
        value_name = "ATTRIBUTE1"
    )]
    attribute1: Option<String>,
```

I want to enforce the users `attribute1` can only provided a value from within an acceptable set of values?

```
acceptable_value = ["ABC", "QWERTY", "XYZ]
```

Can this be enforced as part of clap variable properties? or does this need to happen as part of logic execution later on in the code when using the variable?

Btw, using rust clap 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using [3.2.23](https://docs.rs/clap/3.2.23/clap/index.html).

There are (AFAIK) two way (both requires you to create [`enum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html)):

1. derive [`clap::ValueEnum`](https://docs.rs/clap/3.2.23/clap/trait.ValueEnum.html) on the `enum` (seems prefered way, because the parser can show allowed values)
2. alternatively, implement [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) trait (you can use [`strum`](https://docs.rs/strum/0.24.1/strum/index.html) crate to reduce boilerplate)